# Errors in maven pom defined by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, discord-jda

This question was posted before but with very little information and no solution.
I'm getting an error in my pom file: "Cannot resolve symbol 'runfx.args'"
My project is a maven project based on the javafx archetype. The pom was automatically generated by intelliJ and I only added the JDA dependency and bintray repository (for the JDA dependency) that are the bottom of the pom.
If it is relevant, I can run the program trough IntelliJ without using maven.
[image: Error image]
maven install and maven compile work without errors but maven deploy throws the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:unpack-dependencies (unpack-dependencies) on project MessageSpreadBot: Unknown archiver type: No such archiver: 'pom'. -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven->dependency-plugin:2.6:unpack-dependencies (unpack-dependencies) on project MessageSpreadBot: Unknown archiver type
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at >org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at >sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at >sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at >org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at >org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at >org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at >org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unknown archiver type
>     at >org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:281)
>     at >org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.UnpackDependenciesMojo.execute(UnpackDependenciesMojo.java:91)
>     at >org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at >org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>     ... 21 more
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.manager.NoSuchArchiverException: No >such archiver: 'pom'.
>     at >org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.manager.DefaultArchiverManager.getUnArchiver(DefaultArchiverManager.java:77)
>     at >org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.manager.DefaultArchiverManager.getUnArchiver(DefaultArchiverManager.java:122)
>     at >org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:242)
>     ... 24 more

Here is the full pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ArthurSilva</groupId>
    <artifactId>MessageSpreadBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>MessageSpreadBot</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>ArthurSilva.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>KON</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.3_464</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Thanks

Edit: I tried changing the maven-dependency-plugin version to 3.1.1 and it failed maven install, I changed back to 2.6 and it still fails install. Gives the same error as the one above. I tried cleaning then compiling but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I dont think that is a problem with ${runfx.args}, it is an issue with `MessageSpreadBot` project or dependencies related to it

Comment: Where do you define runfx.args in the pom?  I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your pom and the problem is that the plugin tries to unpack a pom.

> Unpacking d:\Profiles\aclaudel.m2\repository\club\minnced\opus-java\1.0.4\opus-java-1.0.4.pom to D:\tmp\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
>
> [ERROR] [...] Unknown archiver type: No such archiver: 'pom'.

A workaround is to exclude the artifact in the plugin configuration :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>opus-java</excludeArtifactIds>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```